# How to Open Existing Fragment Transaction in Android?

Tags: android

How to Open Existing Fragment Transaction in Android?

Is is used to Replace the existing Fragment with new Fragments from drop down list in action bar?

Comment: what you have tried? can you elaborate bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is what you asked, change

```
FragmentTransaction ft = openFragmentTransaction();
```

to

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to Open Existing Fragment Transaction in Android?

That concept does not make any sense.

> Is is used to Replace the existing Fragment with new Fragments from drop down list in action bar?

When needed, create a *new* `FragmentTransaction`, call `replace()` on it to indicate what is to be replaced, then `commit()` the transaction